# Convert pseudo date string into javascript date object

Tags: javascript

I am receiving the following time from the server:

```
"2010-11-30T23:00:00.000Z"
```

This time gets outputed in three seperate input fields:

```
<input name="day" type="number" value={new Date(myTimeString).getDay()} />
<input name="month" type="number" value={new Date(myTimeString).getMonth()} />
<input name="year" type="number" value={new Date(myTimeString).getYear()} />
```

This results in three inputs being display next to each other with some values like: `1 - 12 - 2010`

Now when the user alters a value, lets say the month gets changed from `12` to `10` I would want to grab the original time string which I get from the server and alter it accordingly to the change.

Is there a "proper" way to do that ? 
All I can think of is storing the original time and then overwriting it with the `str.replace` method at a specific index.

The desired result in that case would be: `"2010-10-30T23:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: You could use MomentJS (http://momentjs.com) for easier date manipulation. The user edits the values, you read them and then use momentJs for a simpler conversion back to the server time format. Using replace could work too. I think it's hard to choose a "proper" way to do this with only the information you posted. Do you use any other frameworks or libraries for example? The use of the "{}" in the value attribute suggest me you are using some sort template system

Comment: I'll take a look at that one - thanks. Yes I am using ReactJS but I didn't want to connect the question to that because its a normal JS question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually shouldn't do manual string manipulation when it comes to Dates.

First you need to convert incomming string to a Date object.

```
var date = new Date('2010-11-30T23:00:00.000Z');
```

Then bind on say change events of corresponding fields using corresponding `Date.prototype.set*` methods. For example [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

```
document
    .querySelector('input[name=day]')
    .addEventListener('change', function setDay() {
       var day = parseInt(this.value, 10);
       date.setDate(day);
    })
```

And then convert date to string when needed using [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method.

```
var dateStr = date.toISOString()
```